# IO Char array not usable in place of a String when using liftM

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a function that I want to print out the value of. It isn't pure as it uses the values from some random functions, which I have already determined that they work correctly. My code is

```
getWord :: [IO Char]
getWord = getRandomConsonant:getRandomVowel:getRandomConsonant:getRandomConsonant: getRandomVowel:[]

main = do
    liftM putStrLn getWord
```

I'm under the impression that `liftM` allows `putStrLn` to print the value of `getWord`, but it fails with the error:

```
word.hs:30:24:
    Couldn't match type `IO Char' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: [IO Char]
    In the second argument of `liftM', namely `getWord'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: liftM putStrLn getWord
    In the expression: do { liftM putStrLn getWord }
```

As this doesn't work, is there any way to print out or execute an `[IO Char]`?

I understand that `IO` objects have to be "executed" in order to get the value from them, but I could not figure out a way to do it. If there is a blatant misunderstanding here, excuse me, as I have just started learning Haskell yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful: `[IO Char]` is **not** `IO [Char]`

If you had something of type `IO [Char]` like `return "hi"`, you could do:

```
(return "hi") >>= print
```

But because your type is `[IO Char]`, which is a list of `IO Char`, you would have to do something like this:

```
sequence [(return 'h'), (return 'i')] >>= print
```

Comment: How would I go along getting an `IO [Char]` from `getWord`?

Comment: Oh my gosh! `Sequence` is the function that I have been looking for for 3 hours now. Thank you so much!

Comment: And use hoogle to find functions.

Comment: @augustss I have been, but I have been looking in all the wrong places. Like I said, I'm very new to Haskell.

Comment: types can help you a lot in solving these kinds of problems. Observe that you have `[IO Char]` and want `IO [Char]`. Search on hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for `[m a] -> m [a]`. Find `sequence` ;)

Comment: Just for clarification's sake, the code I ended up using is `sequence getWord >>= putStrLn`

Comment: @Apanatshka You don't even need to be that general because hoogle allows approximate matches. `sequence` is the first result if you search for `[IO Char] -> IO [Char]`.

Comment: Simply entering `[IO Char] -> IO [Char]` into hoogle gives you `sequence` as the first answer.